# access to files in data lake via open method (abfss)

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

In the past used the mount point to read the files from the data lake using `open`. Now we dont want to do it anymore but use the external location path `abfss`

below code is not working. No such file or directory

```
with open('abfss://urlofcloudstorage/container/file.txt') as f:
data = f.read()
```

I just got aware that `open` method works onlu with local files and it cant read anything from `abfss`

what would be a solution to read the file from datalake. I have seen one option `dbutils.fs.cp` but I dont really want to copy the files locally.  any advice?

UPDATE:I also tried  `dbutils.fs.cp` but as Im using the shared access mode cluster, it is not supported

```
  def decrypt_csv_file_to_pandas(self, source_path, pgp_passphrase, csv_separator):
    """
    Decrypt a csv file directly into a pandas dataframe.
    """
    with open(source_path, 'rb') as f:
      decrypted = self.gpg.decrypt_file(
        file=f,
        passphrase= pgp_passphrase
      )
      print(decrypted.status)
      df_pd = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str(decrypted)) , sep=csv_separator, low_memory=False, keep_default_na=False)
      return df_pd
```

Comment: check this https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/azure-storage.html
you need to configure account name and accesss keys and read it in spark.

Comment: What are you expecting pandas df or spark df?

Comment: I updated with my full script

Comment: @JayashankarGS I have created the storage credential and external locations, using access connector. So setting up the configs is not what I want to do

Comment: @JayashankarGS I have created the storage credential and external locations, using access connector. So setting up the configs is not what I want to do

Comment: install python package `adlfs` where you can read csv file in pandas directly. refer https://pypi.org/project/adlfs/

Comment: files needs to be decrypted first

Comment: is this module relevant for databricks?

Answer (score 0):

Install the Python package `adlfs` in the Databricks library tab or use the command below:

`pip install adlfs`

Then, use the following code:

```py
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem
key = "z9XY91xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyy"
container_name = "data"
file_path = "pdf/titanic.csv"
abfs = AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name="jadls2", account_key=key)

with abfs.open(f"{container_name}/{file_path}", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Here, I have provided the key while configuring, but I would not recommend that. Instead, use a `SAS` token or service principal.

Check [this](https://github.com/fsspec/adlfs/blob/f15c37a43afd87a04f01b61cd90294dd57181e1d/adlfs/spec.py#L328) for more information on arguments for different credentials.

Output:

[image]

I am only printing the file data. In your case, you should decrypt it and read it into a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: I used the `volumes`  and it helped me to solve the problem

Comment: Please add it as an answer, so that it helps the community to find better solution.